# "will … to apply for a visa” or “ will … and apply for a visa”?

Tags: grammar

Thank those who answered [Original question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205163/to-apply-for-a-visa-or-and-applied-for-a-visa), I learned a lot especially the small difference when in past tense.

However, is there any difference if I change them to future tense? (Because neither of below imply the final result)

1. Once he gets the passport, he will go to the Chinese consulate in Toronto and apply for a visa.
2. Once he gets the passport, he will go to the Chinese consulate in Toronto to apply for a visa.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is essentially just ***the same question***. As before, the only real difference is between *actually* doing the second thing, or simply *intending to*, and this isn't affected by whether the actions are in the past, present, or future. Austin: - you might be interested in the example [*Suspect:* "Try and convict me." *Prosecutor:* "Have it your way. We'll try **and** convict you."](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/27024/2637) as mentioned on that ELU answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your reply. 
After thinking about your answers, it seems that the "and" implies the second thing (apply a visa) must happen in future tense or must happened in past tense. For "to", it just tells the purpose but makes no difference to the result.
Can I conclude in this way?

Comment: Semantically, the single sentence *He will go to the Chinese consulate in Toronto and apply for a visa* is equivalent to the *two* consecutive sentences *He will go to the Chinese consulate in Toronto* AND (THEN) *He will apply for a visa*. Note that the *then (**afterwards**)* implication is just because of the context - we assume the application will be made at the consulate, so he can't do this until after he's gone there. There's no such "sequential" implication in other contexts, such as *I will read and watch TV tonight* (in no particular order, but presumably not *at the same time*).

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much the same as before. The "and" case implies the application will automatically follow. The "to" case means he will go there for the purpose of applying, but it does not say he will necessarily be able to. For example, you might choose the "to" form if there was another step between going and applying. Maybe he has to stop at the photographer on the way and get the correct photo.

Heh, or maybe he cynically references the experience of applying in that it usually takes  (me anyway) 3 or 4 tries to actually successfully apply. Letter of invite, photo, confirmed airline flight, confirmed hotel reservation, etc. So he goes to the office to apply, keeping in mind that he will have to come back.

A minor thing. It should be "once he gets the passport" rather than "get." Or possibly "once he has gotten" depending on preference.

Do you go to the consulate for a visa? The place I have gone for a visa for China is the visa office at 393 University, which is not the consulate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
After thinking about your answers, it seems that the "and" implies the second thing (apply a visa) must happen in future tense or must happened in past tense. For "to", it just tells the purpose but makes no difference to the result.
Can I conclude in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The essential difference here is that one is **a combination of two verb phrases** by *and*, and the other is **an adverbial of purpose**.

In the first case, the *and* combines two verb phrases - *go to the Chinese consulate in Toronto* and *apply for a visa*. This means that it is equivalent to two clauses, each using that verb phrase and the same subject.

> ...he will go to the Chinese consulate in Toronto and he will apply for a visa.

In the second, *to apply for a visa* is an adverb of purpose, and expresses *why* he will go to the consulate.