# past simple + to and infinitive form

Tags: past-tense

I have the next sentence in past simple tense.

> Yesterday, I went to visit my friends.

So, I make past simple with verb *go* in past simple form (went), but why do I need to use the verb *visit* in infinitive form? Why not use *visited*?

I know that I could use on this way.

> Yesterday, I went and visited my friends.

**But question is, why in first case is possible just to put first verb in past simple and all other verbs in infitive after word to?**

Comment: You can simply say that Yesterday, I visited my friends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["... to apply for a visa" or "... and applied for a visa"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/205171/9161) A lot of the answers focus on the meaning, but I think FumbleFingers’ answer might help.

Comment: You went (somewhere) for the purpose of visiting your friends. c.f. _Jack and Jill went up the hill to fetch a pail of water_.

Comment: "why do I need to use the verb visit in infinitive form?  Why not use *visited*?" - because that's the way English is.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you friend ! This link solved my problem

Comment: @OnlyYou: Oh! Well I'm glad if my answer to the earlier question solved your problem in its original form. When I compared what you're asking here and what I'd written before, it seemed to me I hadn't actually covered the *specific* issue of "Why the infinitive" (it's because ***went to visit*** actually stands in for *went [somewhere] **in order to** visit someone*). Whatever - I've edited that minor point into the original answer now, but it looks like you didn't need it anyway.